# Counting filled EditText fields

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am building an app, that has *Multiple `EditText` fields and a `Button`*.
For information, `Button` is supposed to open a new `Activity` (I haven't got to that yet), based on filled `EditText` fields,

So, let Suppose
1) if 3rd `Editext` fields have some value, the button will open 3rd `Activity`
2) if 4th `Editext` fields have some value, button opens 4th `Activity`.
and this goes on for every `EditText` fields.

**The question is, How do I count filled editText fields?**

Comment: Your editText fields are fixed or not?. Could you please tell me number of editText fields you have?

Comment: I am going to store the number in an int variable, but I am looking for a way to count the fields.

Comment: I have 6 of them

Comment: Please attach your `Screenshots`, It will help more to understand the scenario of your requirement.

Comment: Okay got your point. And the answer already given by the Ragesh. It is a good solution. Go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you highlighted how to get the filled fields count below countFilledFileds() method will help you. As I understood your problem this will be the complete solution.

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editText1,editText2,editText3,editText4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4 = findViewById(R.id.editText4);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int filledFileds = countFilledFields();
            Log.d("filled", String.valueOf(filledFileds));
            Class newClass = SampleActivity.class;

            switch (filledFileds){
                case 1:

                    newClass = Activity1.class;

                    break;

                case 2:

                    newClass = Activity2.class;

                    break;

                case 3:

                    newClass = Activity3.class;

                    break;

                case 4:

                    newClass = Activity4.class;

                    break;

                default:


            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, newClass);
        }
    });
}

private int countFilledFields() {

    ArrayList<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    editTexts.add(editText1);
    editTexts.add(editText2);
    editTexts.add(editText3);
    editTexts.add(editText4);

    int filledNumber = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i < editTexts.size() ;i++){

        if(editTexts.get(i).getText()!=null && !editTexts.get(i).getText().toString().matches("")){
            filledNumber += 1;
        }

    }
    return filledNumber;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in Activity like this.. But you have to add

`android:tag="et"` in all your Edittext fields of layout.. Change the parent layout type in your code Accordingly. It working as Tested..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 int count=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        int elements = parentLayout.getChildCount();
        View v = null;
        for(int i=0; i<elements; i++) {
            v = parentLayout.getChildAt(i);
           if(v.getTag()!=null && v.getTag().equals("et")){
               count= count++;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

On The base of count you can take decision.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Android SDK at the moment, so there might be some mistakes but you can try something like this:-

```
long numberOfFilledFields = Stream.of(
            editText1.getText().toString(),
            editText2.getText().toString(),
            editText3.getText().toString()) //you can add as many as you want here
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .count();

switch (numberOfFilledFields) {
    case 0:
        //start activity 1
        break;
    case 1:
        //start activity 2
        break;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop your EditText objects and know whether it has value or not;

For example,

```
EditText e1 = ....
EditText e2 = .....
.
.
.
EditText e10 = .....
EditText allText[] = new EditText[]{e1, e2, ...e10};
int filled = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
    if(!allText[i].getText().toString().isEmpty())
        filled++;
}
```

So your filled has the count.

Comment: Can you explain to me, why am I making a new EditText for an array? Can't I just make a String array?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of some flag to set the count of filled editText fields.

Add all your editText references to List. And use the below method to get the count.

```
int count =0;
private int getEditTextViewCount(List<EditText> editTexts){
    for(EditText editText : editTexts){
        if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I forgot about the List

Comment: Are you able to get the count value now?